# How do i change batch of gif's files resolution?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created animated gif file from many small gif's.
I know the animated gif resolution is 512x512
Now i want to create the same animated gif from th same gif's but before i create the animate gif i want first to change each gif file resolution from 512x512 to 1024x1024

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myGifList.Count; i++)
            {

            }
        }
```

In the comboBox1 i have for now only one select a string of "1024x1024". In the constructor of form1 i did:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("1024x1024");
```

In the SelectedIndexChanged event i loop over the file for example the first index in myGifList contain:

```
C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\radar_temp_directory\radar006363.Gif
```

The second index contain:

```
C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\radar_temp_directory\radar006363.Gif
```

Now i want to change each file name from 512x512 to 1024x1024. So if the file radar006363.gif wis now 512x512 change it to 1024x1024 and do it fro all the files in myGifList.

myGifList is List

I want to make like batch resolution convertor for all the files in myGifList from 512x512 to 1024x1024.

Edit:

This is what i tried now:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myGifList.Count; i++)
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(myGifList[i]);
                resizeImage(1024, 1024, myGifList[i]);
                img.Save(@"c:\temp\newimages\" + Path.GetFileName(myGifList[i]));
            }
            unfreez.MakeGIF(myGifList, previewFileName, 8, true);
        }
```

And the resizeImage method:

```
public Image resizeImage(int newWidth, int newHeight, string stPhotoPath)
        {
            Image imgPhoto = Image.FromFile(stPhotoPath);

            int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
            int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;

            //Consider vertical pics
            if (sourceWidth < sourceHeight)
            {
                int buff = newWidth;

                newWidth = newHeight;
                newHeight = buff;
            }

            int sourceX = 0, sourceY = 0, destX = 0, destY = 0;
            float nPercent = 0, nPercentW = 0, nPercentH = 0;

            nPercentW = ((float)newWidth / (float)sourceWidth);
            nPercentH = ((float)newHeight / (float)sourceHeight);
            if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            {
                nPercent = nPercentH;
                destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((newWidth -
                      (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                nPercent = nPercentW;
                destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((newHeight -
                      (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
            }

            int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
            int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);


            Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight,
                      PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution,
                     imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

            Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
            grPhoto.Clear(Color.Black);
            grPhoto.InterpolationMode =
                InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
                new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
                new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            grPhoto.Dispose();
            return bmPhoto;
        }
```

But the file that saved is still 512x512

Comment: Can you please clarify what part of task you have problem with? I'd guess image resizing based on title, but sample code have nothing to do with it. Assuming you need help with something else...

Comment: The problem is how to change each file resolution according to the selection i did in the comboBox. Selected in the comboBox 1024x1024 now how to change each file resolution to 1024x1024.

Comment: Do you have problem with figuring out what selected in combo-box and translating to `{width,height}` pair OR how to [resize image](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+image+resize) OR something else? Retyping what is already present in the post as comment is not exactly clarification.

Comment: Updated my question with what i tried so far. Added one of the methods from the link you gave me about resize image. But after saving the file it's still 512x512.